# Remove class when it's submited and refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, submit

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="bc-uploader" onclick="$('#frontId').click()">
    <div class="bc-upload-text">
      <span>
        Drag and drop a file or select an image
      </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bc-image-text">
      <span>
        Change current image
      </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bc-img-wrapper">  
      <img class="file-upload-image" id="frontId-img" src="/images/investor/35403/frontId.jpg" alt="">
    </div>  
    
    <input type="file" name="frontId" id="frontId" accept="image/*">
  </div>
</div>


--- Submit Buttom ---

<button id="btn-kyc-verification" type="submit" class="bc-btn bc-btn-blue">Submit</button>
```

When I uploaded an image and click submit button, the page refresh and it shows that the " Drag and drop a file or select and Image " overlay the image. That text should be gone when I press submit and page refresh. Any way When I click submit button, the page refresh and the class " bc-upload-text " remove or hidden?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript way

```
var text = document.querySelector(".bc-upload-text");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn-kyc-verification");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
   text.remove();
});
```

jQuery way

```
var text = $(".bc-upload-text");
var btn = $("#btn-kyc-verification");

btn.on("click", function(){
   text.remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it does disappear when it click. but after the page reload, the text appear again. any Idea?

Comment: JavaScript is responsible for the state in web application, if you refresh the page the state is gone, if you want to keep the state you should consider backend language and database integration.